# Running CGI application in window 7 IIS

Tags: iis, cgi, gsoap

I have create a application in C/C++ that has the extension .cgi followed the instruction in gSoap specification, now i want to deploy my application in IIS, how can i do it?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should go through the following tutorials first.

http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/how-to-run-a-cgi-program-under-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5

http://community.microfocus.com/microfocus/cobol/net_express__server_express/w/knowledge_base/23805.deploying-cgi-web-application-on-iis-7.aspx